# Is it unsafe to put php in the /wp-content/uploads directory?

Tags: php, uploads, security

Pretty straight forward question, but I'll provide any clarifications needed.

The reason I'm asking is this: I created a child theme that pulls in a `custom-functions.php` file. This allows devs to customize the site without editing the child theme. I know that's the purpose of a child theme, but for the sake of brevity I won't go into the reasoning behind all that.

I put `custom-functions.php` in `/wp-content/uploads/customizations`. Is this a security risk? And if so, what's a better place to put it. I don't want to put it in my child theme because it'll get overwritten when the theme is updated.

Comment: In this case you're supposed to fork the child theme, or the parent, creating a _grandchild theme_ by putting templates in `uploads` to get around it isn't good ( is there a reason you didn't ask about your problem but instead asked about the solution? This seems like a classic X Y problem ). Needing grandchild themes or some equivalent is usually a sign that things aren't right

Comment: Why can't this file just be a plugin? A plugin is just a PHP file in wp-content/plugins after all.

Comment: Thanks guys, I posted [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/385377/what-is-the-best-approach-to-avoid-a-grandchild-theme-in-this-situation) that asks about the problem and not the solution.
@JacobPeattie, does a plugin seem like a good fit for that situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes it is unsafe**, though not for the reasons you think. ***DO NOT DO THIS.***

If your developers can upload a PHP file to your site that gets executed, then that PHP file can undo all other security measures that you put in place. The location of the file is irrelevant. Functionally, there is no difference from editing plugins directly.

Additionally, a common security enhancement is to prevent PHP execution in the uploads folder, and assume any PHP in the uploads folder is malicious.

Either way, your proposed development process is *highly unusual* and problematic. **I strongly advise against this.** Moving the files uploaded to another folder will not improve security.

Do not let developers upload PHP to the uploads folder. It is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. When you say:
_If your developers can upload a PHP file to your site that gets executed, then that PHP file can undo all other security measures that you put in place. The location of the file is irrelevant._
Does that mean it's equally unsafe to allow developers to create or edit a child theme?

Comment: WordPress doesn't sandbox code, a hook is a hook, WP can't tell the difference between code that came from a child theme, a plugin, a parent theme, etc. Once the code is loaded, it's all just code. The only exception is that things are loaded in different orders, and that WP by default looks at specific locations for template files to load. But once those files are loaded they can do as they please. If a dev can run code on your server then they can do anything they want

Comment: E.g. I could write a template for you, and inside that template put a `wp_insert_user` call that creates an admin user for myself, or downloads a PHP shell to let me bypass WP completely and give me limited SSH access and a file browser.

Comment: However, if you don't trust these developers, why are you working with them? Use version control to manage code, take a backup before hand, and pay a fair hourly rate with a reputable freelancer/agency

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified this. I'm not worried about devs. When I asked about security, I meant against hacking. By putting php in the `/uploads` directory, am I creating some kind of back door that malicious actors can take advantage of?

Comment: I posted [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/385377/what-is-the-best-approach-to-avoid-a-grandchild-theme-in-this-situation) that might clarify things. Thanks for your input so far!

Comment: _pay a fair hourly rate with a reputable freelancer/agency_, as a developer I totally agree!

Comment: PHP in the uploads folder implies a user managed to upload something they shouldn't

Comment: Thanks Tom. Let me see if I can clarify. I myself put PHP in the uploads folder and used `include` to pull it into `functions.php` in the child theme. I'm not worried about anything that other developers do on the site. All I'm wondering is, by putting PHP in the uploads folder am I creating some kind of backdoor or vulnerability that hackers can exploit?

Comment: It is good practice to eliminate all PHP execution in the uploads folder at the Nginx/Apache level, and assume any PHP found there is malicious. I strongly advise _against_ this plan. I see no advantages. If you want an unequivocal statement to reassure you that this is okay, I hereby veto all attempts to provide it and state in no uncertain terms, this is a terrible idea, do not do it, stop looking for excuses for it to be ok, it is not. Note that the first 3 words of my answer are ***Yes, it is unsafe***

Comment: Letting developers upload PHP files to your uploads folder is not the solution to your problem, you shouldn't even consider it as an option. Do an immediate U turn and abandon this path, it is a dead end with lots of problems. Other solutions exist, all of the are superior in basic fundamental ways

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'll mark this as the accepted answer.